# why the zip function did not give the expected result in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
a = enumerate('abcdef')
b = enumerate('ghi')

for i, j in zip(a, b):
        print(i, j)
        if i[0] == 0:
            next(itertools.islice(zip(a, b), 1, 1), None)
```

For the above code, I expect the following result as I advance zip(a, b) by 1:

```
 ((0, 'a'), (0, 'g'))
 ((2, 'c'), (2, 'i'))
```

However, it still gives the same result as the following code:

```
iter1 = enumerate('abcdef')
iter2 = enumerate('ghi')

for i, j in zip(a, b):
        print(i, j)
```

output:

```
((0, 'a'), (0, 'g'))
((1, 'b'), (1, 'h'))
((2, 'c'), (2, 'i'))
```

why the statement next(itertools.islice(zip(a, b), 1, 1), None) does not advance zip(a, b)?

Comment: where is `a` , where is `b` ? what do they have to do with `iter1`+`iter2` ?

Comment: ...works fine for me (python 3.6). did you name your generators correctly (`ìter1` vs `a`)?

Comment: sorry, there is mistake, it should be iter1 instead of a, and iter2 instead of b.

Comment: I run the above code in python 3.6, and it gives the expected result. Thanks all for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [3.6 zip](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) returns iterators and it works as you expect:

```
a = enumerate('abcdef')
b = enumerate('ghi')

for i, j in zip(a, b):
        print(i, j)

        if i[0] == 0:
            next(itertools.islice(zip(a, b), 1, 1), None)
```

it will skip the `(1,)` tuples as zip returns iterators.

The [2.7 zip](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) returns a list of tuples, and both statements are unrelated as the `zip(a,b)` are seperate list, both using unrelated enumeration sequences.

So for 2.7 they are not skipping the `(1,)` tuples.

Output 3.6:

```
(0, 'a') (0, 'g')
(2, 'c') (2, 'i')
```

Output 2.7:

```
((0, 'a'), (0, 'g'))
((1, 'b'), (1, 'h'))
((2, 'c'), (2, 'i'))
```

You are running 2.7 from your demo output.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: I just found out that the zip function works differently in python 2.7 and 3.6. Thanks for your help!